# How can I change the alert time for tag-specific search alerts to immediate instead of 'daily' or 'weekly'?

Tags: search, alert, sitefeed

I've set up an alert to send me notification any time a specific tag is used... based on the search page for that tag.

Unfortunately, the only alert options are for "daily" or "weekly". My team needs to be able to receive an alert immediately. I'm still new to Sharepoint, so any OOTB help would be appreciated. I can figured some coding out if it's clearly broken down.